# Compile ocl-icd2.1.3 in CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux, opencl, centos6

I am trying compile ocl-icd2.1.3 in CentOs 6.3 but get error.

```
ocl_icd_loader.c:40: error: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
ocl_icd_loader.c:41: error: unknown option after '#pragma GCC diagnostic' kind
ocl_icd_loader.c:44: error: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
In file included from ocl_icd_loader.h:31,
                 from ocl_icd_loader.c:48:
ocl_icd.h:32: error: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
ocl_icd.h:33: error: unknown option after '#pragma GCC diagnostic' kind
ocl_icd.h:41: error: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
In file included from ocl_icd_loader.c:50:
ocl_icd_debug.h:29: error: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
ocl_icd_debug.h:30: error: unknown option after '#pragma GCC diagnostic' kind
ocl_icd_debug.h:35: error: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
In file included from ocl_icd_loader.c:50:
ocl_icd_debug.h:69: error: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
ocl_icd_debug.h:72: error: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
make[2]: *** [libOpenCL_la-ocl_icd_loader.lo] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio `/home/juliancho/Descargas/ocl-icd-2.1.3'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio `/home/juliancho/Descargas/ocl-icd-2.1.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

please help me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Show the offending line(s).

Comment: Um, it's very nice you found time to thank me, but where are the offending lines? No one can help you without seeing them.

Comment: mmm Excuse me please. I am going to reading, because I don't understand offending lines. Thank you. I will write soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your source contains a line like

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
```

This kind of pragma was introduced in GCC 4.6. Your gcc release is too old to handle it.

You can:

- upgrade your gcc
- remove `-Wunknown-pragmas` or equivalent from the makefile
- remove `-Werror` or equivalent from the makefile
- remove `#pragma GCC diagnostic push`, `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop` from the source

but only the first option is reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will to upgrade gcc. the next time I will write better my problems. I promise. I will describe my results.

Comment: -Wmissing-prototypes "is valid for C / Obj but not for C + + [Enabled by default]

Comment: Hi, I try to compile EmguCv, .Net wrapper to the OpenCV. Tks.

Comment: Don't pass -Wmissing-prototypes to the compiler when compiling C++ code. You may have to wrap the pragmas in #ifndef __cplusplus/#endif pairs to disable them for C++. .Net is not C++. It is unclear how gcc is able to work with .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday upgrade gcc and now got this:

`Wmissing-prototypes "is valid for C / Obj but not for C + + [Enabled by default]`